# Is there any to shorten the code that needs variables?

Tags: c#

I've always wondered, are there ways to shorten this kind of code?

```
private void Update01()
{
    item01.text = item01n + "\nCost: " + Math.Round(cost01, 2) + "\nYou have: " + n01;
}

private void Update02()
{
    item02.text = item02n + "\nCost: " + Math.Round(cost02, 2) + "\nYou have: " + n02;
}

private void Update03()
{
    item03.text = item03n + "\nCost: " + Math.Round(cost03, 2) + "\nYou have: " + n03;
}
.
.
.
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have repeated code, there are always ways to refactor to reduce the duplication. Are you hoping for something like `Update(item01, item01n, cost01, n01)`?

Comment: Simple, return `string` instead of `void` and pass in 3 parameters.

Comment: First Write, Second Copy, Third Refactor http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/First_Write,_Second_Copy,_Third_Refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 12seconds said, just return a string and pass in 3 variables:

```
private string GetUpdate(item, cost, n)
{
    return item + "\nCost: " + Math.Round(cost, 2) + "\nYou have: " + n;
}
```

And then simply do:

```
item01.text = GetUpdate(item01n, cost01, n01);
item02.text = GetUpdate(item02n, cost02, n02);
item03.text = GetUpdate(item03n, cost03, n03);
```

Comment: But if you have 20 such items, that'd still be a fair bit of duplicaton.

Comment: @Dylan True, but you would hope that at that stage he would use a list of classes and a for loop :)

Comment: Hi, do I need to create a new class for this? I have red lines under my variables.

Comment: You need to provide the types. I put placeholders as names, but since i don't know what types item, cost, and n are instances of, I didn't include those.